MS Excel VBA - The code runs perfectly except for the last 4 lines
My code runs for everything except 4 lines.
I have Excel VBA Code that runs perfectly and does what it should do, but the last 4 lines moves up 2 lines. Which means the data that should be in the last line is in the third line from the bottom.
This code should take the data in one spreadsheet, hide all empty rows based on if column A has data, and then map this data to another spreadsheet in the same workbook that is a template that comes from Xero Accounting Software.
Sub MapDataToXeroTemplate4()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColSource As Long
    Dim lastColTemplate As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim col As Long

    ' Set your source and template sheets
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Budget Manager Overall Budget") ' Change to your source sheet name
    Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall Budget") ' Change to your Xero template sheet name
    
    ' Find the last row with data in the source sheet (Column A)
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Find the last column with data in the source sheet and template sheet
    lastColSource = wsSource.Cells(1, wsSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastColTemplate = wsTemplate.Cells(1, wsTemplate.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ' Reset row in template where data starts
    j = 2 ' Assuming row 1 in the template contains headers

    ' Loop through the source sheet and hide rows without values in column A
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming the first row is headers, start from row 2
        If IsEmpty(wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            wsSource.Rows(i).Hidden = True
        Else
            wsSource.Rows(i).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next i

    ' Loop through the source sheet and map to the Xero template
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming row 2 onwards has data
        If Not wsSource.Rows(i).Hidden Then
            ' Dynamically map columns from source to template
            For col = 1 To Application.Min(lastColSource, lastColTemplate) ' Map up to the minimum number of columns
                wsTemplate.Cells(j, col).Value = wsSource.Cells(i, col).Value
            Next col
            
            ' Increment j only after mapping the current row
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "Data mapping completed!"
End Sub

Please assist if you maybe know why the bottom 4 lines gives that problem. I am unable to share the files because it contains sensitive data, but I think dummy files can be created.

Does the template sheet have 2 rows less than you are expecting ? It could be an anomaly in the data rather than the code.

Do you mean bottom lines of code or data?

I don't see any problem with this code. Before running the code, check if you template is clear.

I see now that the template has 155 lines of data without the empty lines. The source sheet has 157. Somewhere there are two extra lines created.

What do you confuse with? Per your code, lines are created on the template sheet not on the source one. Thus, you are not able to state "Somewhere there are two extra lines created". The only case when there are more lines on the source sheet visible then created on the template sheet is when some last cells in the column A of the source sheet are empty. Rows of those cells will not be hidden, but content of the template sheet will be correct.

Side note, why looping wsTemplate.Cells(j, col).Value = wsSource.Cells(i, col).Value when you can wsTemplate.Rows(j).Value = wsSource.Rows(i).Value?  You could even use a .range(.cells(j,1),.cells(j,colNum)).value and make the determination for colNum = Application.Min(lastColSource, lastColTemplate) to avoid a whole separate loop for columns.

Additional side note, why loop at all for the second sheet?  You can select the source range (.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy) and paste to the new sheet (.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues), as you're having no other modifications to the data.  As such you would have an exact range and be able to call out what is copied and pasted and should remove any doubt regarding row counts because it is copying through the last row.

Building off of my comments regarding the loop after you've hidden data.  You can complete your loop for determining wsSource.Rows(i).Hidden then have a simple finish (replacing the remainder of your script):
Dim colNum as Long:  colNum = Application.Min(lastColSource, lastColTemplate)
With wsSource
    .Range(.Cells(2,1),.Cells(lastRow,colNum)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End with
With wsTemplate
    .Range(.Cells(2,1),.Cells(lastRow,colNum)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End with


I will look into improving the code as you have advised. And in terms of the amount of rows in the source sheet, I used a counta function to check how many rows there are with data and it amounted to 157 lines, where the template only contains 155 and this confused me. But I will look into it, thank you very much for the assistance.
